# SOAUI Groovy Getresponsenode.value from xml is null

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui, web-api-testing, nodevalue

I have a problem where I have tried very different scenarios,
I am a fresh automation tester for api services and I'm using soapui and groovy to my services.

So here is the problem:
I have a service that responds to a request and I want to get a specific data/value from the response. That's where the problem starts, because I have passed the xpath of the variable and its value but when I print a log on a groovy script it prints a null.

Can anyone who had some problem similar to this help? Thanks in regard.

Where is the part of my response that matters:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns0:outputMessage xmlns:ns0="urn://soa/es/Theater/GetBarProducts/Root">
         <ns1:Header xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.soa.com/SharedResources">
            <ns1:timeout>14500</ns1:timeout>
            <ns1:creationTime>2019-09-23T11:07:20+01:00</ns1:creationTime>
            <ns1:iTrackingID>f7e8ea93-9736-4380-97ab-846b9cc69fbd</ns1:iTrackingID>
            <ns1:eTrackingID>>f81c1210-88fa-4188-8358-b86825d5df70</ns1:eTrackingID>
            <ns1:application>CINEMAS</ns1:application>
            <ns1:user>APIQMS</ns1:user>
            <ns1:process>GetBarProducts</ns1:process>
            <shar:AccessData xmlns:data="urn://soa/es/Theater/GetBarProducts/Data" xmlns:jms1="http://www.tibco.com/namespaces/tnt/plugins/jms" xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.soa.com/SharedResources" xmlns:oas="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:oas1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:root="urn://soa/es/Theater/GetBarProducts/Root" xmlns:shar="http://xmlns.soa.com/SharedResources" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
               <shar:userOS>os</shar:userOS>
               <shar:remoteHost>host</shar:remoteHost>
               <shar:remoteIP>ip</shar:remoteIP>
               <shar:otherInfo>info</shar:otherInfo>
            </shar:AccessData>
            <ns0:Status xmlns:jms1="http://www.tibco.com/namespaces/tnt/plugins/jms" xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.soa.com/SharedResources">
               <ns0:eCodes>
                  <ns0:eCode>COM-000</ns0:eCode>
                  <ns0:eDescription>Success</ns0:eDescription>
               </ns0:eCodes>
               <ns0:eNative>
                  <ns0:eCode>OK</ns0:eCode>
                  <ns0:eDescription/>
                  <ns0:eSystem>ArpuxNew</ns0:eSystem>
               </ns0:eNative>
            </ns0:Status>
         </ns1:Header>
         <ns1:DataOutput xmlns:ns1="urn://soa/es/Theater/GetBarProducts/Data">
            <ns1:TheaterProducts>
               <ns1:TheaterProduct Description="Menu_Pequeno" ID="C101" Price="5.4" Size="Pequeno" Type="Menu Pipocas" UUID="00aacfa5-8169-4e53-b315-ee9682461936">
                  <ns1:Group GroupID="App1" Name="Menus"/>
                  <ns1:SubGroup GroupID="App2" Name="Menu Clássico"/>
                  <ns1:Files>
                     <ns1:File Height="400" Path="//cdn.nos.pt/cinemas/products/files/400x400/null" Width="400"/>
                     <ns1:File Height="225" Path="//cdn.nos.pt/cinemas/products/files/225x225/null" Width="225"/>
                     <ns1:File Height="1000" Path="//cdn.nos.pt/cinemas/products/files/1000x1000/null" Width="1000"/>
                  </ns1:Files>
                  <ns1:TheaterProductItems>
                     <ns1:TheaterProductItem>
                        <ns1:TheaterProducts>
                           <ns1:TheaterProduct Description="Caixa Doce Pequena" ID="B028" Index="1" Size="Pequeno" Type="Doces" UUID="6fad59b3-b623-4f59-9fda-a25cf4cc2738">
                              <ns1:Group GroupID="02" Name="Pipocas"/>
                           </ns1:TheaterProduct>
                           <ns1:TheaterProduct Description="Caixa Sal Pequena" ID="B032" Index="2" Size="Pequeno" Type="Salgadas" UUID="4c69ead4-04a6-4413-9e21-bd25a9ab51ee">
                              <ns1:Group GroupID="02" Name="Pipocas"/>
                           </ns1:TheaterProduct>
                           <ns1:TheaterProduct Description="Caixa Mista Pequena" ID="B070" Index="3" Size="Pequeno" Type="Mistas" UUID="663f57b3-0534-4e75-9f41-fedbef008b4a">
                              <ns1:Group GroupID="02" Name="Pipocas"/>
                           </ns1:TheaterProduct>
                        </ns1:TheaterProducts>
                     </ns1:TheaterProductItem>
                     <ns1:TheaterProductItem>
                        <ns1:TheaterProducts>
```

The values I want to get is the ID and the UUID of second TheaterProduct that is like this:

```
<ns1:TheaterProduct Description="Caixa Doce Pequena" ID="B028" Index="1" Size="Pequeno" Type="Doces" UUID="6fad59b3-b623-4f59-9fda-a25cf4cc2738">
                              <ns1:Group GroupID="02" Name="Pipocas"/>
                           </ns1:TheaterProduct>
```

Then there is this script that I created but it returns null for reasons I don't know, since I have tried every possible solution I have thought and searched.

Here is the script in groovy:

```
//vai buscar o valor prentendido ao response
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder

//Using context object retrieve the response of a soaprequest - AddRequest
def res = context.expand('${SOAP#response}')
//log.info res

//To parse and get the tags in req/res we have to use XMLHolder class
def response = new XmlHolder(res)

//To retrieve the result of request and response tags using getNodeValue Method

//def reqvalue1 = response.getNodeValue('//ns1:Session[1]/@UUID')
def reqvalue1 = response.getNodeValue('//ns1:TheaterProduct[1]/@UUID')
def reqvalue2 = response.getNodeValue('//ns1:Header/ns1:DataOutput/ns1:TheaterProductItems/ns1:TheaterProductItem/ns1:TheaterProducts/ns1:TheaterProduct[1]/@ID')


log.info reqvalue1
log.info reqvalue2

//cria um ficheiro com o valor da resposta pretendido
//new File('sessionID').text = reqvalue1


//Descomentar a linha seguinte para correr na propria maquina
//e comentar a linha que cria o ficheiro
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue('TheaterProductUUID',reqvalue1)
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue('TheaterProductID',reqvalue2)
```

The case is I have used this line that works for a different service but it doesn't work here, which is really weird.

Here a proof of the line working on a different service:

[image: Different service with the line of the script working and getting a value]

Here is my response for the service I need:

[image: Service getting a null value]

If someone knows about any solution or something like it would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

XML needs to have namespaces defined and associated with each node. Your code

```
def reqvalue1 = response.getNodeValue('//ns1:TheaterProduct[1]/@UUID')
```

uses namespace `ns1`, however you did not define it.

For read-only operations, it is perfectly safe to use the wildcard namespace, like so:

```
def reqvalue1 = response.getNodeValue('//*:TheaterProduct[1]/@UUID')
```

Also note that internally SoapUI keeps everything represented as XML. You can ready the node value right at your `context.expand()` line, line so:

```
def reqvalue1 = context.expand('${SOAP#Response#//*:TheaterProduct[1]/@UUID}')
```

SoapUI [tips & tricks](https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/tips-tricks.html#iterate-nodes) has some additional information.

Comment: Thanks for the help @SiKing . I have tried other defenition due to the namespace  and it worked like this : def reqvalue6 = response.getNodeValue('*//*:TheaterProduct[3]/@UUID')                                                                                                                                                        log.info reqvalue6 ->  Wed Sep 25 12:15:21 BST 2019:INFO:663f57b3-0534-4e75-9f41-fedbef008b4a